# Why doesn't pm3d work with view map? (Gnuplot)

Tags: gnuplot

basically I've been trying to plot the Mandelbrot set but I've encountered a little problem. I organized the points I want to plot in three columns (x,y,z) like

> 1 3 5
>
> 1 4 6     (the x values aren't separated by spaces)
>
> 1 4 8
>
> 2 5 8
>
> 2 1 4
>
> 2 5 7

and so on. This is what I get when I tried to use splot with pm3d and view map.
[image: Image obtained by using pm3d map]

I tried using `plot "data.dat" with images` but I always obtained an error. The image using `pm3d` only shows a circle but I find this weird since there are some points inside the circle that don't have `Z=0` coordinate. If I'm not being  clear enough, here are the same points but plotted without `pm3d`
[image: Image obtained by using splot]

What can I do to view the plot like a heat map without the problems I mentioned?

Comment: Since you have a one to many map from (x,y) to z (z in your data is not a function of (x,y), how do you want this translated into a heat map?

Comment: Actually it is well defined function of (x,y) to z, maybe the image was misleading. I solved the problem by arranging the data a little better, still, thanks for responding.